# MySQL: Iterating and updating records in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table with records as below:

```
USER  | STATUS
--------------
user1 | 1
user2 | 1
user1 | 1
user2 | 1
user1 | 0
user2 | 1
user3 | 1
```

I want to add a field `COUNT` and update the table so that `COUNT` will have values as below:

```
USER  | STATUS | COUNT
----------------------
user1 | 1      | 1
user2 | 1      | 1
user1 | 1      | 2
user2 | 1      | 2
user1 | 0      | NULL # Don't want to update where STATUS=0
user2 | 1      | 3
user3 | 1      | 1
```

I don't know much about Stored Procedures, and the ones I tried did not really give the output I want.

Much appreciated if someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: If your table doesn't have a PK, it will be non-deterministic to iterate it, if it is not locked!

Comment: It does have a primary key - and auto increment id. I just didn't show it because I want to update based on the values of USER field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an id column, you can use the query below (you have to add a column called `prevUser`, then you can drop that column afterwards)

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN prevUser varchar(50);
SET @prevUser = '';
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE users 
SET count = (@count:=IF(@prevUser != user,1,@count+1)),
    prevUser = (@prevUser := user)
WHERE status != 0
ORDER BY user,id;
ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN prevUser;
```

<kbd>[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65ae30/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

No need for a stored procedure. I added an auto_increment column, otherwise it would be non-deterministic.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (id int auto_increment primary key, `USER` varchar(5), `STATUS` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`USER`, `STATUS`)
VALUES
    ('user1', 1),
    ('user2', 1),
    ('user1', 1),
    ('user2', 1),
    ('user1', 0),
    ('user2', 1),
    ('user3', 1)
;

ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN COUNT int default null;
```

Query:

```
UPDATE t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
  id,
`USER`, `STATUS`,
CASE WHEN (@my_count := IF(@prevUser != USER, 1, @my_count + 1)) IS NULL THEN NULL
WHEN (@prevUser := USER) IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE @my_count END AS `COUNT`
FROM
t,
(SELECT @my_count := 0, @prevUser := NULL) init
WHERE
STATUS != 0
ORDER BY USER, id
  ) sq ON sq.id = t.id
SET t.COUNT = sq.COUNT;
```

Result:

```
| ID |  USER | STATUS |  COUNT |
|----|-------|--------|--------|
|  1 | user1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 | user2 |      1 |      1 |
|  3 | user1 |      1 |      2 |
|  4 | user2 |      1 |      2 |
|  5 | user1 |      0 | (null) |
|  6 | user2 |      1 |      3 |
|  7 | user3 |      1 |      1 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76847/1/0)

Comment: This is just what I want! However it doesn't work as expected on my MySQL box. In that, the count is getting incremented sequentially regardless of if the USER value changes. That is, for the example above, ID=2 has COUNT=2, ID=3 has COUNT=3 and so on. My MySQL version is 5.6.14-62.0-log.

Comment: Well, it works for me in 5.6.6 too, as you can see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbef1/1/0 Have you changed anything? Removed the `ORDER BY` for example?

Comment: No I hadn't changed the query (apart from using actual table & field names, of course).

Answer (score 0):

A version without using session variables

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN `count` INT;

UPDATE users u JOIN 
(
  SELECT id,
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) 
      FROM users
     WHERE user = t.user
       AND id < t.id
  ) count
    FROM users t
   WHERE status = 1
) q
    ON u.id = q.id
   SET u.count = q.count
```

Outcome:

```
| ID |  USER | STATUS |  COUNT |
|----|-------|--------|--------|
|  1 | user1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 | user2 |      1 |      1 |
|  3 | user1 |      1 |      2 |
|  4 | user2 |      1 |      2 |
|  5 | user1 |      0 | (null) |
|  6 | user2 |      1 |      3 |
|  7 | user3 |      1 |      1 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ed5f/1)** demo